# 'Invalid object name' SQL error after connection has been active for several days

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, datasource

We have a Java spring web project deployed to Tomcat 8.5. When web application starts we build one datasource and connect to a SQL Server. When it is needed, we get a connection from connection pool associated with the datasource and execute some native queries. The connection is always closed to return it to the pool.

When the web application is up for the first several days, everything works fine. However, after several days, we start to get exception like:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'dbo.patients'.
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:107)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:107)
```

The table "dbo.patients" quoted above is just an example. The error could happen to other tables randomly.

We check the backend database and the tables exist! Rebooting the Tomcat will fix the problem for a while but the issue keeps coming back.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that the exact same function / query works instantly after you restart? Because it seems you are trying to do something to a table that actualy does not exist. A typo maybe?

Comment: The functions/queries work for several days and then start to get exception randomly. We print out the table names and queries.  We can execute the queries in Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: Perhaps the current database is not set correctly or the connection is to a different server instance. Either way, the error is clear. The table does not exist in the dbo schema or in the current database of the connection. You will need to debug the code more thoroughly.